# How to make a shell script that opens a file and adds lines at the end of the file and then saves?

Tags: shell

I want to make a shell script that opens a file and adds lines at the end of the file, then saves it.

More concretely, I want to make the following commands a shell script:

```
$ ulimit -n
1024
```

if its less than 65536 then,

```
$ vim /etc/security/limits.conf
```

Add at the end of file:

```
root soft nofile 65536
root hard nofile 65536
soft nofile 65536
soft nofile 65536
```

!wc in vim. Then reboot.

How to make this shell script?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
if [ `ulimit -n` -lt 65536 ]; then
    {
    echo "root soft nofile 65536"
    echo "root hard nofile 65536"
    echo "soft nofile 65536"
    echo "soft nofile 65536"
    } >> /etc/security/limits.conf
    reboot
fi
```

Comment: Or, better: `{ echo "..."; echo "..."; echo "..."; echo "..."; } >> /etc/security/limits.conf` which only opens (and closes) the file once.

Comment: In the comment, I needed the semi-colons; in your script, it's better for readability to replace them with newlines, as shown.  If the `}` is on the same line as a command, you do need a semi-colon before it, unlike the `)` in a sub-shell.  Weird, but so.

Answer (score 3):

To answer the question in the title,

```
$ echo "root soft nofile 65536" >> /etc/security/limits.conf
```

will add the line `root soft nofile 65536`  at the end of the file.

To reboot, in many linux systems, you just have to do :

```
$ reboot
```

And to test a value , you could do something like :

```
if [ "`ulimit -n`" -lt "65536" ]; then
    # do stuff
fi
```

So finally, your script would look like :

```
#!/bin/sh
if [ "`ulimit -n`" -lt "65536" ]; then
    file='/etc/security/limits.conf'

    {
        echo "root soft nofile 65536"
        echo "root hard nofile 65536"
        echo "soft nofile 65536"
        echo "soft nofile 65536"
    } >> $file

    reboot
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

first check the limit setting, if it's less than 65536, then append the lines to the end of file and reboot

```
if [ `ulimit -n` -lt 65536 ];then
cat >> /etc/security/limits.conf << EOF
root soft nofile 65536
root hard nofile 65536
soft nofile 65536
soft nofile 65536
EOF
reboot
fi
```